# Extracting the first two components of a version number

Tags: python, strings

What's the most pythonic way to extract a substring by delimiter position?

i.e. something like slicing a string, but where the index is based on the delimiter position, rather than the character position in the string.

I have a version string `"1.2.3.dev0"` and I want to extract the first two components `"1.2"`.

Currently I'm using:

```
>>> delimiter = "."
>>> version = "1.2.3.dev0"
>>> short_version = delimiter.join((version.split(delimiter)[0:2]))
>>> print(short_version)
1.2
```

Is this the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of a simpler way of doing the splitting.

The only thing that comes to mind is replacing `[0:2]` by `[:2]` to take the first two components of the version number, since the first index in the slice notation defaults to the beginning of a sequence object.

However, instead of using a string, you could use a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) with integer elements to represent a version number, which would allow you to do comparisons more easily:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> VersionNumber = namedtuple('VersionNumber', 'major minor')
>>> version_str = '1.2.3.dev0'
>>> version = VersionNumber(*map(int, version_str.split('.')[:2]))
>>> print(version)
VersionNumber(major=1, minor=2)
>>> if version.major < 2:  # don't care about minor version
...     print('Need at least version 2.')
```

You could easily convert it back to a string:

```
>>> '.'.join(map(str, version))
'1.2'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions, like this:

```
import re
print(re.match('^([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)', '1.2.3.dev0').groups(1)[0])
```

Comment: You might want to add a `[0[` at the end to get only the first group and not a tuple containing only the first group.

Comment: I'd prefer the original version. If, for example, you wanted to extract the first three instead of two components, you simply would have to change a `2` to a `3` in the code, whereas here it would be more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the number of parts after the first two will not change, you can use [rsplit(delimiter, maxsplit)](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rsplit.html) :

```
'1.2.3.dev0'.rsplit('.', 2)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use find like this:
string.find(delimiter) return position of the delimiter

```
print(version[0:version.find(".")+2])
```

Comment: You should mark your code as code. Just select it all and press Ctrl+K or use the `{}` button on the toolbar.

Comment: This assumes there is exactly one character between the first and second dot.

Comment: There is no need for this assumption as find return number which is the index of the first occurrence(By default First) of delimiter but we assume that we need a specific occurrence